# extract specific words from a string

Tags: r

I need to extract all the single words that appear after the "join" word in the below string in R.

```
db<- c("select *
        FROM a
        left join bd on bd.id=a.id
        left join ca on ca.id=a.id
        left join dc on dc.id=a.id
        where a.names != NULL")
```

My Result should be 
"bd" "ca" "dc"

Is there any best possible approach for above mentioned query.

Comment: Look into `stringr::str_extract()`.

Comment: To start with str_extract_all(string = db,'[a-z]+\\.')

Comment: In case you do not know them yet, you need regular expressions to specify what you're looking for (that's the `'[a-z]+\\.'` part in @karthikbharadwaj's comment. The stringr documentation has a [nice introduction into the topic.](http://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html) See also [the "Strings" chapter in R4DS](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html) for more basics.

Comment: @karthikbharadwaj "bd." "a."  "ca." "a."  "dc." "a."  "a."  This is the result I am getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `stringr::str_match_all(.)` to match your string to a regular expression. You can use a feature of regular expression called "capture groups". That means, you can group parts of the regular expression using `(` and `)`. Their contents then show up separately in the results:

```
library(stringr)
res <- str_match_all(db, "join ([a-z]+)")
res
[[1]]
     [,1]      [,2]
[1,] "join bd" "bd"
[2,] "join ca" "ca"
[3,] "join dc" "dc"
```

You see that the result is a list of one element (can be seen by the `[[1]]` output part or if you use `str(res)`). If you would have provided a vector of strings instead of only one string, this list would have more elements. Inside each list element, there is a matrix of strings. Each row of the matrix is one place of the input string where the regular expression matched. Each column of the matrix is one of the capture groups `(...)` of the regular expression. The first column is always the whole match. Therefore, the second column holds what you're looking for.

As mentioned in the comments, look into [R for Data Science > Strings](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html) and [stringr documentation > Regular expressions](http://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html) to learn about the topic.

Comment: What if I need to get the string as a output, lets say if I change ad,ca and dc to ad_ca_dc, ca_ad_dc and dc_ad_ca respectively

Comment: I used [:graph:] and I got the Result. The tutorial helped me in finding this.

Comment: @VikramJois Great to see it worked! Be aware though, that these character classes like `[:graph:]` might give different results, depending on the locale (language setting of your computer). [Here is a blog post which gives a glimpse](http://www.rexamine.com/2013/04/properly-internationalized-regular-expressions-in-r/). However, I do not really get this topic, and the package `stringr` is based on the package `stringi` which the authors claim solves those problems. I do not know how thought. Just keep it in mind in case you encounter strange problems in the future.